# Dynamics Crm 2013 get all column doesnt work

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics

Im using dynamics crm 2013 and sdk. I wrote code below and try to getting all column for entities but doesnt work.

And my second problem is that I want to getting one column for example "new_onaysayisi" but return column is "contactid" .

```
   public static List<Entity> GetEntityList(string entityName, int memberType)
    {
        GetOrganisationService();

                 var query = new QueryExpression
        {
            EntityName = entityName,
            ColumnSet =new ColumnSet("new_onaysayisi"),
            Criteria = new FilterExpression { FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And },
        };

        query.Criteria = new FilterExpression();

        query.Criteria.Conditions.Add
        (
            new ConditionExpression("new_uyelikturu", ConditionOperator.Equal, memberType)
        );


        var entities = _service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities.ToList();



        return entities;

    }
```

Something is wrong but i couldnt find  the solution.

Where am i wrong? Thanks for help.

```
    public static List<Entity> GetEntityList(string entityName, int memberType)
    {
        GetOrganisationService();

        var cs = new ColumnSet { AllColumns = true };
        var query = new QueryExpression
        {
            EntityName = entityName,
            ColumnSet =cs,
            Criteria = new FilterExpression { FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And },
        };

        query.Criteria = new FilterExpression();

        query.Criteria.Conditions.Add
        (
            new ConditionExpression("new_uyelikturu", ConditionOperator.Equal, memberType)
        );


        var entities = _service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities.ToList();



        return entities;

    }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably because the values are not populated.

In your first example the `id` of the primary entity is always returned. I would suspect `new_onaysayisi` is not being returned because it is not populated.

In the second example, the `AllColumns` code looks good, but again you only get the columns back that are actually populated.

If you use `entity.GetAttributeValue`, that will either return a value or null, which can make it easier to work with records.

Comment: Thanks James its work:)     var t=   entity.GetAttributeValue<int?>("new_ykonaysayisi3");